# Exporting data.frame in R into a .txt file

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that has 15 columns and looks like the following:

```
 Word    Syllable   TimeStart   TimeEnd   Duration   PitchMin   PitchMax TimePitchMin
 Einen   "aI        0.00         0.11     0.11       98.173     106.158        0.053
 Einen   n@n        0.11         0.24     0.13      106.158     123.176        0.110

TimePitchMax PitchSlope IntenMax IntenMin TimeIntenMax TimeIntenMin PitchAccent
0.110        140.443   83.794   82.583        0.095        0.051          no
0.210        169.359   83.875   80.458        0.210        0.234          no
```

I want to save the data into a .txt file. But when I use standard write.table(table, "outfile.txt") method the result looks like a mess.

What appropriate arguments can be used to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

The print screen of the mess output:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "looks a mess"? Can you be specific about what you don't like in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the structure of your table with str(table) before you export? It looks like the table may contain some corrupt variable names and/or variable, which may un turn cause export problems.  In an ideal case, when you do str(table), you should see that the table object is a data.frame (or tibble) with proper variable names and values. If you see variable names like """ or c(9,11,11, ...) etc., that's a signal that your problem is with how you create table, not how you export it.

Comment: When I used str(table) method I can see that one of the columns has another data frame in it that was caused by adding another data frame "PitchAccent" to the current data frame with the help of table1$NewColumn <- table2. And that is the reason why I can't export the data to txt file.

Comment: that explains why you couldn't export your data properly. You can only append columns to a data frame using the $ notation. To append an entire data frame (with the same number of rows as the original data frame), simply use cbind.data.frame(dataset1, dataset2), where dataset1 is the original data frame and dataset2 is the data frame to be appended.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you use write.table(table, "outfile.txt", sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)? That should help you create a tab-delimited text file.

If the output still looks like a mess, you can export your file as a csv with write.csv(table, "outfile.txt", row.names=FALSE).

Comment: Hm, it looks like a mess in both cases.